# Gson Parser unable to create objects from array

Tags: java, json, gson, pojo

I am attempting to write a Gson parser to create POJO's from JMS messages.
The messages are delivered in Text format in the following style:

```
{  
"priceUpdate":[  
  {  
     "symbol":"EUR/USD",
     "entryType":"0",
     "price":"1.09286"
  },
  {  
     "symbol":"EUR/USD",
     "entryType":"1",
     "price":"1.0929"
  }
 ]
}
```

I am trying to create Pojo objects for each item in the Array but the code fails when I attempt to parse:

```
public void consumeMessage(String text) {
    try {
        PriceUpdateTypeDTO updates = gson.fromJson(text,PriceUpdateTypeDTO.class);
        for (PriceUpdateItemDTO u : updates.items) {
            if (u.getEntryType() == "0") {
                connectedMarket.setBidPrice(Double.parseDouble(u.getPrice()));
            } else {
                connectedMarket.setOfferPrice(Double.parseDouble(u.getPrice()));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get a NullPointer when running on Tomcat Server

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.markets.ticker.PriceStreamClient.consumeMessage(PriceStreamClient.java:25)
```

Here are my POJO classes:

```
public class PriceUpdateTypeDTO {


    private ArrayList<PriceUpdateItemDTO> items;
    //getter & setter
}


public class PriceUpdateItemDTO {

    private String symbol;

    private String entryType;

    private String price;
    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: `priceUpdate` vs `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of your ArrayList in *PriceUpdateTypeDTO* needs to have the same name as the array in the JSON:

Change

```
 private ArrayList<PriceUpdateItemDTO> items;
```

to

```
 private ArrayList<PriceUpdateItemDTO> priceUpdate;
```

or vice-versa (change the name of the array in the JSON to "items")